# OSX equivalent of SymGetLineFromAddr or SymGetLineFromAddr64

Tags: macos, backtrace, mach-o, dyld, dwarf

I want to add source file and line numbers to my backtraces, on Windows there is a nice function SymGetLineFromAddr64 which provides such information if available. I can't find something similar on mac.
dladdr outputs only symbol name without file information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no public equivalent to `SymGetLineFromAddr64` on OS X, but you can get source file and line number with the [atos(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/atos.1.html) developer tool.

Here is some sample code to get a fully symbolized backtrace.

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static NSArray * Backtrace(NSArray *callStackReturnAddresses)
{
    NSMutableArray *backtrace = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSNumber *address in callStackReturnAddresses)
    {
        NSString *hexadecimalAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%0*lx", (int)sizeof(void*) * 2, address.unsignedIntegerValue];
        NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
        NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
        task.launchPath = @"/usr/bin/xcrun";
        task.arguments = @[ @"atos", @"-d", @"-p", @(getpid()).description, hexadecimalAddress ];
        task.standardOutput = pipe;
        NSString *symbol = @"???";
        @try
        {
            [task launch];
            NSData *data = [pipe.fileHandleForReading readDataToEndOfFile];
            symbol = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            symbol = [symbol stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
            [task waitUntilExit];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {}
        [backtrace addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", hexadecimalAddress, symbol]];
    }
    return [backtrace copy];
}

static void test(void)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", Backtrace([NSThread callStackReturnAddresses]));
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Running this code will produce the following output:

```
0x000000010000134e test (in a.out) (main.m:31)
0x000000010000131b main (in a.out) (main.m:36)
0x00007fff8c0935fd start (in libdyld.dylib) + 1
```

Comment: Note that `atos` (and `xcrun`) isn't installed on non-developer systems, so this won't work in deployed applications. Another option to look at is `backtrace_symbols()`

Comment: Indeed, this will only work on a system with developer tools installed. If you *really* need source file name + line number info you will have to use the private [CoreSymbolication](https://github.com/mountainstorm/CoreSymbolication) framework or write your own DWARF parser.

Comment: according to what I read about CoreSymbolication it's exactly what I need. I'll try. I have no any desire to write my own DWARF parser, DWARF looks very scary.

Comment: Well, `atos` is just a simple CLI wrapper to some CoreSymbolication functions. Rather than dealing with a private framework, maybe you could just bundle the `atos` binary into your app. Also, in case you need to symbolicate crash reports, you should look into the `symbol‌icatecrash` binary from Xcode’s `DTDeviceKitBase` framework.

Comment: dealing with a private framework doesn't sound such scary. I just will make it optional, in order if something is changed there (like it is removed) my backtraces would not contain source file/line number information.

Comment: I've provided implementation for my application. CoreSymbolication works as expected and even better.